# Flow clearTimeout is incompatible with TimeoutID

Tags: javascript, react-native, flowtype

I am working on a React Native App, that I require to use Flow.

I am still getting around the entire concepts of `let arr: Array<React$Element<Component>> = []`

But there is somethings that for as much as I research I cannot figure out how to define the type of the variable that I will use to clearTimeout.

using what this guy said: [0.63.x regression: setTimeout() & setInterval() return types broken](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5627#issuecomment-356070874)

he says to use:

```
const foo: TimeoutID = setTimeout(() => {}, 300);
const bar: IntervalID = setInterval(() => {}, 300);
```

but eventually I have to make a `clearTimeout()` and I get:

> Cannot call `clearTimeout` with `this.playerTimeOut` bound to `timeoutId` because null or undefined (see line 17) is incompatible with `TimeoutID` (see https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.78.0/lib/core.js#L733).

Code:

```
playerTimeOut: ?TimeoutID = null;

componentDidMount() {
  const { children } = this.props;
  const { index } = this.state;

  this.playerTimeOut = setTimeout(() => {
    clearTimeout(this.playerTimeOut);

    this.setState({
      index: index >= this.total ? 0 : index + 1
    });
  }, parseInt(children[index].attr.runningtime) * 1000);
}
```

Really appreciate any help or constructive improvements :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what the magic you're implementing, but would notice that timeout will be cleared right first run, so you don't need to explicitly call the `clearTimeout`.

However, if you're sure you need this, what flow see is:

```
playerTimeOut: ?TimeoutID = null;
```

so, it might be null or undefined.

To fix this either:

a) define without [maybe type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe):

```
playerTimeOut: TimeoutID; // no question mark, no default value.
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEDMBsHsHdQFAGNIEMDO7QEFQG8FRQAHNATwFMAnAFQEsBbCgeQFcAXALlHqeg4CSAEQDcCBE3YALaABMAFAEp8hUNLroAdKVSVajFh1ABeUOgrteFfu3lKTAPhVEXoFBVT6+Heeq069KzZ2RTFXAF8AGlAARgAGBNCEcPEUoA)

b) [refine maybe type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/#refining-maybe-types-) using `if` condition:

```
if(this.playerTimeOut) {
   clearTimeout(this.playerTimeOut);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your awesome explanation! Of course, without the maybe type and saying, this is just a unregistered variable of this type, it should clear the timeout but still remain of type TimourID! your awesome!! One more thing THANK You for explaining with the b) method it helped with another question I had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53302201/flowtype-property-msg-is-missing-in-null-or-undefined/53304807#53304807 So thank you!