# Flowtype property 'msg' is missing in null or undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, flowtype

I am finding hard to use Flow. I understand that `Array.find` can return or be undefined.

So by reading this: [github: Array.find on Array<{...}> raises](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3514)

I did that and added `void` to the type to. However now I get the error:

> Cannot get `stageMsg.msg` because property `msg` is missing in null or undefined (see line 92).

Check code to see where the error is specifically.

I understand why it is giving me the error, there is no `msg` in undefined. what I don't know is how to solve this issue.

Here is the code:

```
type StageMsg = {
  stage: number,
  msg?: string
};

let stageMsg: void | StageMsg = this.stages.find(
  (obj: StageMsg) => obj.stage === this.state.stage
);

msg = (
  <Msg text={this.state.msg !== "" ? this.state.msg : stageMsg.msg} /> //<---- [Error here].
);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to check that `stageMsg` exists before accessing a property on it.
So you could wrap your assigment to `msg` in `if (stageMsg) { ... }`, or use an inline expression like `stageMsg && stageMsg.msg`.
Also note that you could use [maybe](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/) syntax instead of a union with `void` e.g. `let stageMsg: ?StageMsg`

Comment: Thanks mate this really helped! I was really banging my head into it to! simple . . . I just did the wrong condition >.< lame me! thanks mate!